# Not sure if creating a script is the answer- any advice

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to automate a process in sheets if possible. My example is below.

Jane Doe fills out a survey in Forms (name, date, email, what class she wants to teach) which then appears in the responses spreadsheet. John Smith fills it out as well so now I have two rows with responses on my spreadsheet. I want to know if google sheets can create a new tab (sheet) down at the bottom for Jane (sheet2) and another one for John (sheet3) automatically (and so forth for every survey response) that copies all their answers to their own tab. The reason for this is, I have to contact Jane and ask her additional questions and it would be easier to have her own tab down at the bottom where I can add the additional information. I would also add the student names to her tab to keep track of them. Same goes for John and every other person that fills out the survey. Does that make sense?
I posted the question in the Google Doc Editors and they suggested I submit here because I might need to run a script instead.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1akTLcXJnjwg8B-aSOP8JvrXBFRwXMkeluwi35WU1d98/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Form Submit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers?hl=fr-FR#available_types_of_triggers) in Apps Script to trigger the script that I provide below so that every time anyone submits an answer in your linked Spreadsheet a new Sheet with the name of the person that submitted the response will be added with the details of that submission.

Use the following script which has self explanatory comments in your Spreadsheet (in your Spreadsheet menu bar go to **Tools-> Script Editor** and paste and save the following):

```js
function FormSubmit() {
// Get the sheet where all form responses are added
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  
  // Get all the data from the new response. I have used the method
  //getRange(row,col,number rows, number columns) and getValues which as
  // it returns a 2D array I have flatten it for easier use latter on.
  var getData = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1,1,5).getValues().flat();
  // Create new sheet setting its name to the property name that we had in our original
  // sheet
  var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().insertSheet().setName(getData[1]);
  
  // iterate over all the questions and details in the form and copy their values from
  // the original sheet and paste them into the new sheet we just created
  for(i=0;i<getData.length;i++){
  newSheet.getRange(1, i+1).setValue(getData[i]);
  }
}
```

For getting this to work and add the adecuate sheet every time there is an answer, in the script editor you must go to the menu bar and select **Edit -> Current project's triggers**. That will take you to a new page where you must click on **Add trigger** and select the following:

- Function to run: FormSubmit
- Select event source: From Spreadsheet
- Select event type: On form submit

Finally click **Save** and you will be ready to go !